# Unsafe, `noexcept` and no-overhead way of accessing `std::variant`

Tags: c++, c++17, variant

[`std::variant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) provides the following access functions:

- [`std::get_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/get_if): take *pointer* to `variant`, return *pointer* to alternative.

  ```
  template <std::size_t I, typename... Ts> 
  auto* std::get_if(std::variant<Ts...>* pv) noexcept;
  ```

  - > If `pv` is not a null pointer and `pv->index() == I`, returns a pointer to the value stored in the variant pointed to by `pv`. Otherwise, returns a null pointer value.

    This means that `get_if`'s implementation roughly looks like this:

    ```
    template <std::size_t I, typename... Ts> 
    auto* std::get_if(std::variant<Ts...>* pv) noexcept
    {
        if(pv == nullptr) return nullptr;
        if(pv->index() != I) return nullptr;
        return &(pv->real_get<I>());
    }
    ```
- [`std::get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/get): take *reference* to `variant`, return *reference* to alternative, *`throw`* on invalid access.

  ```
  template <std::size_t I, typename... Ts>
  auto& std::get(std::variant<Ts...>& v);
  ```

  - > If `v.index() == I`, returns a reference to the value stored in `v`. Otherwise, throws `std::bad_variant_access`.

    This means that `get`'s implementation roughly looks like this:

    ```
    template <std::size_t I, typename... Ts> 
    auto& std::get(std::variant<Ts...>& v)
    {
        if(v.index() != I) throw std::bad_variant_access{};
        return v.real_get<I>();
    }
    ```

---

**I want an unsafe access function that:**

- Is `noexcept`.
- Takes a *reference* to a `variant`, avoiding any `pv == nullptr` check.
- Has *undefined behavior* if `v.index() != I`.

Why? Because there may be some situations where I am 100% sure that a particular `variant` instance contains a specific type in a code path. Also, it would be useful when writing generic code that already separately checked `v.index() != I` *(e.g. writing my own `visit`)*.

Example implementation:

```
template <std::size_t I, typename... Ts> 
auto& unsafe_get(std::variant<Ts...>& v)
{
    return v.real_get<I>();
}
```

**Is there something like this in the standard?** I couldn't find it. If not, **is this possible to implement for `std::variant`, or do I need to roll out my own `variant` implementation?**

Comment: I don't think the standard library will provide/allow such a type-unsafe function.

Comment: Maybe worth asking on std-discuss. This could always be proposed as a future extension.

Comment: Why does the noexcept condition matter that much, or at all? How have you tested this?

Comment: Use a visitor. Move the code part which makes you 100% sure that a given type is in the variant into the visitor. It might turn out that you don't need _that_ part of code or need it just as an assert. This makes your code way faster.

Comment: LWG doesn't put `noexcept` on things that can lead to UB, so #1 and #3 are de facto mutually exclusive.

Comment: I also don't see why `*std::get_if<I>(&my_variant)` cannot be optimized down to what you want, in principle.

Comment: @T.C.: Even if inlining allows the compiler to optimize it down to one conditional check, it cannot get rid of the check to see if `I` matches the current index. There's no way to statically know that for any particular `my_variant`.

Comment: @NicolBolas But in the case of an index mismatch, the resulting null pointer dereference is UB, so I don't see why the compiler can't assume that it never happens and optimize away the index comparison.

Comment: @T.C.: It could. But since there's no guarantee that it will, and there's no long history of compilers offering such a guarantee, there's no reason to rely on it.

Comment: @NicolBolas That's why I said "in principle".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As pointed out by @T.C. in the comments, your first and third desiderata are mutually incompatible. This was spelled out in [**N3279**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3279.pdf), titled "Conservative use of noexcept in the Library".

There are essentially two classes of contracts: narrow and wide. A **wide** contract for a function or operation does not specify any undefined behavior.
Such a contract has no preconditions. Only functions with wide contracts are marked `noexcept` in the Standard Library.

OTOH, a **narrow** contract is a contract which is not wide. Narrow contracts for a functions or operations result in **undefined behavior** when called in a manner that violates the documented contract. They cannot be marked `noexcept`. Instead, the best you can expect is that they are documented as "Throws: Nothing."

It appears that you are out of luck and no such unchecked access is provided in the current proposals for `std::variant`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to implement the whole variant on your own. 
Though unrestricted unions can be helpful - they at least solve putting multiple types in the same location with alignment issue handled.