# Zero overhead handling of std::variant in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, variant

Is it possible to use `std::variant` as a zero-overhead and safe container for handling situations like the following using Visual Studio?

```
#include <variant>
extern bool bar(),foo();

bool lessForMyVariants(const std::variant<int*, float*, double *> x, const std::variant<int*, float*, double *> y) {
    if (x.index()!=y.index()) {
        return x.index()<y.index();
    } else {
        switch(x.index()) {
        case 0:
          if (x.index()==0 && y.index()==0)
            return *std::get<0>(x)<*std::get<0>(y);
          break;
        case 1:
          if (x.index()==1 && y.index()==1)
            return *std::get<1>(x)<*std::get<1>(y);
          break;
        case 2:
          if (x.index()==2 && y.index()==2)
            return *std::get<2>(x)<*std::get<2>(y);
          break;
        default:
          return foo();
        }
    }
    return bar();
}
```

Since `x.index()` and `y.index()` have the correct values in the case-statements there should be neither the possibility of exception (for incorrect call of std::get) nor call of `bar()`.

Gcc can do that optimization - https://godbolt.org/z/6vsqPz5qe - but I cannot get the same for Visual Studio.

Note:

- I know that the if-statements are redundant, but they are needed to trigger the optimization for gcc. Removing them would be nice.
- I'm not interested in unsafe access in contrast to [Unsafe, `noexcept` and no-overhead way of accessing `std::variant`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42052122/unsafe-noexcept-and-no-overhead-way-of-accessing-stdvariant)
- Alternatives to std::variant are welcome, assuming they solve the issue.
- The calls of foo and bar are just there to check the compiler output.

I noticed that many thought that std::visit would be faster than a switch. Testing found the opposite:

```
// ConsoleApplication1.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//
#include <variant>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
typedef std::variant<int*, float*, double*> V;
extern bool bar() {
    throw 2;
}
extern bool foo() {
    throw 3;
}
bool lessForMyVariantsSwitch(const std::variant<int*, float*, double*> x, const std::variant<int*, float*, double*> y) {
    if (x.index() != y.index()) {
        return x.index() < y.index();
    }
    else {
        switch (x.index()) {
        case 0:
            if (x.index() == 0 && y.index() == 0)
                return *std::get<0>(x) < *std::get<0>(y);
            break;
        case 1:
            if (x.index() == 1 && y.index() == 1)
                return *std::get<1>(x) < *std::get<1>(y);
            break;
        case 2:
            if (x.index() == 2 && y.index() == 2)
                return *std::get<2>(x) < *std::get<2>(y);
            break;
        default:
            return foo();
        }
    }
    return bar();
}
bool lessForMyVariantsSwitchConstSimple(const std::variant<int*, float*, double*>&x, const std::variant<int*, float*, double*>&y) {
    if (x.index() != y.index()) {
        return x.index() < y.index();
    }
    else {
        switch (x.index()) {
        case 0:
           
                return *std::get<0>(x) < *std::get<0>(y);
            break;
       case 1:
            
                return *std::get<1>(x) < *std::get<1>(y);
            break;
        case 2:
           
                return *std::get<2>(x) < *std::get<2>(y);
            break;
        default:
            return foo();
        }
    }
    return bar();
}
bool lessForMyVariantsSwitchConst(const std::variant<int*, float*, double*>&x, const std::variant<int*, float*, double*>&y) {
    if (x.index() != y.index()) {
        return x.index() < y.index();
    }
    else {
        switch (x.index()) {
        case 0:
            if (x.index() == 0 && y.index() == 0)
                return *std::get<0>(x) < *std::get<0>(y);
            break;
        case 1:
            if (x.index() == 1 && y.index() == 1)
                return *std::get<1>(x) < *std::get<1>(y);
           break;
        case 2:
            if (x.index() == 2 && y.index() == 2)
                return *std::get<2>(x) < *std::get<2>(y);
            break;
        default:
            return foo();
        }
    }
    return bar();
}


// helper type for the visitor #4
template<class... Ts>
struct overloaded : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };
// explicit deduction guide (not needed as of C++20)
template<class... Ts>
overloaded(Ts...)->overloaded<Ts...>;

bool lessForMyVariantsVisit(const std::variant<int*, float*, double*> x, const std::variant<int*, float*, double*> y) {
    return std::visit(overloaded{
        [] <typename T>(T * lhs, T * rhs) { return *lhs < *rhs; },
        [&](auto,auto) { return x.index() < y.index(); } },
        x, y);
}
bool lessForMyVariantsVisitConst(const std::variant<int*, float*, double*>&x, const std::variant<int*, float*, double*>&y) {
    return std::visit(overloaded{
        [] <typename T>(T * lhs, T * rhs) { return *lhs < *rhs; },
        [&](auto,auto) { return x.index() < y.index(); } },
        x, y);
}
template <class P> size_t checkSort(std::vector<V> const& v, P p, const char* whichSort) {
    size_t z=0;
    std::vector<V> v2;
    auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    constexpr int maxNum = 1000000;
    for (int j = 0; j < maxNum; ++j) {
        v2 = v;
        //std::ranges::sort(v2, p);
        std::sort(v2.begin(), v2.end(), p);
        z += v2[0].index();
    }
    auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << whichSort <<" took "
        << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(t2 - t1).count()*1.0 / maxNum
        << " nanoseconds per\n";
    return z;
}

int main()
{
  
        int varr[4] = { 6,7,1,10 };
        float farr[4] = { 5.0f, 1.2f, 4.5f, 2.2f };
        double darr[4] = { 5.0, 1.2, 4.5, 2.2 };
        std::vector<V> v;

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
            v.emplace_back(varr + i);
            v.emplace_back(farr + i);
            v.emplace_back(darr + i);
        }
       
        double z=0;
        z+=checkSort(v, lessForMyVariantsSwitch, "lessForMyVariantsSwitch");
        z += checkSort(v, lessForMyVariantsVisit, "lessForMyVariantsVisit");
        z += checkSort(v, lessForMyVariantsSwitchConst, "lessForMyVariantsSwitchConst const&");
        z += checkSort(v, lessForMyVariantsVisitConst, "lessForMyVariantsVisitConst const&");
        z += checkSort(v, lessForMyVariantsSwitchConstSimple, "lessForMyVariantsSwitchConstSimple const&");
        std::cout << "dummy: " << z;
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately the switch-statement was faster with /O2 (Visual Studio 2022).

- lessForMyVariantsSwitch took 90.0676 nanoseconds per
- lessForMyVariantsVisit took 125.441 nanoseconds per
- lessForMyVariantsSwitchConst const& took 88.1962 nanoseconds per
- lessForMyVariantsVisitConst const& took 121.182 nanoseconds per
- lessForMyVariantsSwitchConstSimple const& took 96.642 nanoseconds per

Similar with g++ 11.3.0 and clang++ 14.0.0 under WSL-Ubuntu, with the minor difference that clang++ had lessForMyVariantsSwitchConstSimple as the fastest.

Comment: `std::get_if` should be an option there.

Comment: Have you tried `std::visit` [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/1o9781zzT)? You don't even have to write unreachable code as `bar()`/`foo()`.

Comment: Not quite what you asked, but I believe `std::visit` is cheaper than using a `switch` statement.

Comment: I have now tried std::visit and it is about 30% slower; so that wouldn't work - I will add more details later

Comment: @Jarod42 I tried std::visit by copying that part - as shown above, and it is just slower.

Comment: Similar results with [quick-bench](https://quick-bench.com/q/i0ojCg21MaJ7Vrm1dF1gfBwSJpw) (`lessForMyVariantsSwitchConstSimple` wins in both gcc/clang).